# Check nested list value combinations that match on another list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list that represents a **tic tac toe board**.

```
board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I have a list of win combinations that are on a nested list.

```
wins = [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
```

I have a function that iterates the `wins` list. If a combination from the `wins` list exists on the `board` list, the function should return true.

Example:

```
board = [4,5,6,9]

def win(board):
    wins = [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]] 
    for w in wins:
        if w in board:
            return True
        return False
```

This should (i think) return True, cause 3 digits from the win list are on the board list but by some reason it keeps returning false.

Am I missing something on my code?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does `board` represent? The positions where one of the players has set the marks?

Comment: When you check `if w in board` you check `if [4,5,6] in [4,5,6,9]` for example. Now - `4 in [4, 5, 6, 9]` return true, but your `board` doesn't have any item which is a **list** itself.

Comment: `a in b` tests if the list `b` contains the `a` but your list doesn't contain `a`. You are looking for equality against a subset of `b`

Comment: @tobias_k that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it checks only first 'win' combination (`[7,8,9]`) and then just returns false. Second, you can't check it using `in` operator like so.

```
>>> [1,2,3] in [4,1,2,3,6]
False
```

So if you want to check if the combination is on the board (in the same order):

```
for w in wins:
    if ''.join(w) in ''.join(board):
        return True
else: # note indentation. else is part of for expression.
    return False
```

if the order does not matter:

```
for w in wins:
    if all(x in board for x in w):
        return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your code:

- `w in board` does not check whether the individual elements of `w` are in `board`, but whether `w`, as a whole, is an element of `board`, which is not the case for any `w`
- you return `False` as soon as the first `w` does not work out (assuming that the first check would work), instead of after you tested *all* the `w`

Instead, you can use a nested [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check whether for *any* of the winning combinations, *all* the elements are in the `board`.

```
>>> wins = [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]] 
>>> board = [4,5,6,9]
>>> any(all(x in board for x in w) for w in wins)
True
```

Alternatively, since order does not matter and each of the elements should appear only once, you can use `sets` instead (note the inner `{...}` in `wins`) and use [`issubsetof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
>>> wins = [{7,8,9},{4,5,6},{1,2,3},{7,4,1},{8,5,2},{9,6,3},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}]
>>> any(w.issubset(board) for w in wins)
True
```

Comment: Very clean and simple! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to dedent your return false, because you end cycle after first iteration

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if elements in board match an element of win. Your current code would always return False since it checks if [4, 5, 6, 9] is in an element of win. One way to check if elements in board matches a winning combination is to intersect the sets of board wth all elements in win:

```
def win(board):
wins = [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]] 
for w in wins:
    if list(set(w) & set(b)) == w:
        return "won"
return "no win"
```